# How to get a certain runtime version for vs.net

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Certain files are autogenerated by vs.net and put the runtime version in the header comments.  What is frustrating is that now, these files are always showing up as modified on my machine because two developers have different runtimes.  How do I determine how to get my colleague's machine to the same runtime?

I have this:

2.0.50727.5448

And my colleague has this:

2.0.50727.5444

Our machines are both fully updated through MS update.  So how can I determine what to install to get his machine to the same version?

Basically where to I find the updated to get 2.0.50727.5448?

Additional info: This autogenerated file is actually coming from creating service proxy code files from svcutil.exe, but that file on both machines is the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do something similar for debugging purposes and stumbled upon a quick and dirty solution. There's probably a better way, but this could tide you over in the meantime.

Search [mskbfiles.com](http://www.mskbfiles.com/) with a core framework dll, like [mscorwks](http://www.mskbfiles.com/mscorwks.dll.php) or [sos](http://www.mskbfiles.com/sos.dll.php); i.e. go to the web page and search within it for your framework version. If you find it then follow the link to the associated hotfix or security update and install it.

I successfully used this approach to update the framework on a machine from 2.0.50727.5446 to 2.0.50727.5448. Specifically, I found the required version of mscorwks was in security update [MS11-078](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2572077/).